# identity and self

Tags: identity

From "The Craft of Family Therapy" by Salvador Minuchin, etc.:

> A self is created in a context populated by significant "others" at
>   different historical periods in the life of a person, but it has a
>   single **identity** who partakes through life and is influenced--and
>   exerts influence--on other **selves**. And while we talk about our
>   **identity** as if it is a unit, in effect we can unwrap the latent **identities** that have formed through out lives.

This quote is so confusing! Does the identity in "it has a single identity" the same thing as the one mentioned in the next sentence? Does the author think a person has more than one self?

Thanks for response.

Answer (score 1):

The quote is not really in philosophy, so you might also want to ask in a sociology or psychology SE question. But I wrote my PhD dissertation on selfhood.

I see in this quotation three concepts:

(1) The self as a socially constituted entity. *A self is created in a context populated by significant "others" at different historical periods in the life of a person.* The idea here is that to be a self (here meaning the sort of entity that has self-consciousness) is to be built on certain constituting relationships to others. In other words to be a self is to receive certain ideas and thought processes from others (i.e., one's society).

(2) The self's identity as the self's unity. *it has a single identity who partakes through life and is influenced--and exerts influence*. This is to say that the self is a unified node that operates in relation to other nodes in the social matrix.

(3) Identity as a complex notion. *And while we talk about our identity as if it is a unit, in effect we can unwrap the latent identities that have formed through out lives.* Here, the point is that [social identity theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_identity_theory) and several contemporary philosophical views of the self point out that the identity of the self varies by social context. In other words, sometimes my configuration is a college professor, some times as a white guy (esp. in Japan), sometimes as a man. And these notions of identity don't always overlap; rather different identities matter in different interactive contexts.

I don't know if that made things any clearer for you but that's what I see happening in that quote. There's a lot to unpack there.

Comment: Nice answer! How is this not philosophy?!

Comment: The *quote* is not in philosophy. (Presumably, it's in family therapy?). Not many philosophers tread these lines of thought -- it's much more common in religion, sociology, and psychology.